# How to make a login form work

Tags: html

I have created a very basic login form in html. How can I check the form to see if it's valid? Here's my form:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <font size="6">Username:</font>
        <input type="text" style="font-size:30px;height:45px;width:300px;" name="username" id="username"/>
        <br>
        <font size="6">Password:</font>
        <input type="password" style="font-size:30px;height:45px;width:300px;" name="password" id="password"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" style="font-size:30px;height:45px;width:300px;" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean valid?  What have you tried? Have you looked on google?  Take a look at this page to learn  more about stackoverflow:  -->  [ask]    -- it will help you to properly phrase your question and also help you understand what needs to be in your question for others to help you

Comment: btw welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JavaScript/JS/Login-form-Validation-in-javascript.aspx?id=5

You can find JS Form validation in the above link if you want to do the validation in the front end itself.

For backend validation: If you are using java, set form action to a servlet and get the username and password in the servlet using request and check for the corresponding username and password combination in DB and if it matches redirect from there to the next page.